# How can I set the space between footnotes and page number equal to the space I have between text and page number?

Tags: spacing, footnotes

The page numbers are at the bottom center of my document. From time to time, I add footnotes but realised that the space between the footnotes and the page number is not the same for the case I do not use footnotes (normal text). Does anyone know, how I can make them the same?

Comment: Can you show us the issue with a small compilable example?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I was just about to create a document to show my problem. However, the problem does not show up anymore. I guess, I have to check the preamble myself before uploading it.

Comment: Since footnotes are implemented as floats and floats are supposed to fit inside the text area, this shouldn't happen.  At least, not without adding negative \vspace to the note.